# Create one folder for all files uploaded with google apps script and web app form

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a web app with GAS. This web app have three inputs (Input 1, input 2, Upload file input), two for metadata and one for upload files. The upload input is a multiple upload file input. When I submit the form, the code must generate a folder for all files that I upload and register the data in a google sheet. For example i upload the file 1 and the file 2 with name or entry of the input 1 for the folder's name. But, when I go to  google drive, the code generate two folders with the same name, in other words, for example, two folders, the first with the file 1 with the folder's name "folder 1" and the second with the file 2 with the folder's name "folder 1".  How I get to generate only one folder for all files? What is wrong with my code? Can you help me?
greetings!
Here's my code:

```html
<html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta
        name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
      />
      <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
      />

      <title>TITLE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <h4>Ingrese datos</h4>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <input
              class="form-control"
              id="numsip"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Set Name for folder"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <input
              class="form-control"
              id="rut"
              type="number"
              placeholder="Set idnumber"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
            <input
              class="form-control"
              id="files"
              type="file"
              placeholder="Seleccione Archivos"
              multiple
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <button id="contactar" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="enviardatos()">
          Generar carpeta
        </button>
      </div>
      <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
      ></script>
      <script
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
      ></script>
    </body>

    <script>
      function enviardatos() {
        var sip = document.getElementById("numsip");
        var rut = document.getElementById("rut");
        var array = { numsip: sip.value, rut: rut.value };
        const f = document.getElementById("files");
        [...f.files].forEach((file, i) => {
          const fr = new FileReader();
          fr.onload = (e) => {
            const data = e.target.result.split(",");
            const obj = {
              fileName: f.files[i].name,
              mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1],
              data: data[1],
            };

            google.script.run
              .withSuccessHandler((id) => {
                console.log(id);
              })
              .addNewRow(array, obj);
          };
          fr.readAsDataURL(file);
        });

        alert("Se ha generado carpeta");
      }
    </script>
  </html>
</html>
```

Here is the serverside function for google apps script:

```js
function addNewRow(array, obj) {
  var timestamp = new Date();
  var parentFolderId = 'URLPARENTFOLDER';
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId);
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var foldercreated = parentFolder.createFolder('SIP ' + array.numsip + '/' + array.rut);
  var idfolder = foldercreated.getId();
  var url = 'URLSHEET';
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ss = values.getSheetByName('DATA');
  ss.appendRow([array.numsip, array.rut, timestamp, user, idfolder]);

  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(obj.data), obj.mimeType, obj.fileName);
  return foldercreated.createFile(blob).getId();
}
```

*I omitted the "doGet" function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to put the uploaded files to the specific folder.
- When the folder name of `"SIP "+array.numsip+"/"+array.rut` is existing in `parentFolder`, you don't want to create the folder with the same folder name. You want to put the files to the existing folder.

### Modification points:

- In this case, I would like to propose to modify both the function of `addNewRow` at Google Apps Script side and `enviardatos()` in Javascript side.
- In your current script, the new folder is created every run by `var foldercreated = parentFolder.createFolder("SIP "+array.numsip+"/"+array.rut)`. So this part is required to be modified.

  - It checks whether folder of the same folder name is existing.
- And, your Google Apps Script side, I think that `var parentFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId);` at the bottom of function is not used.
- But, there is one more important point in your script. The script in `[...f.files].forEach((file, i) => {,,,})` is run with the asynchronous process. By this, even when the script at Google Apps Script side is modified, the duplicate folder names are created. So it is required to also modify the script of Javascript side.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows. Please modify the function of `addNewRow` as follows.

### Modified script:

#### Google Apps Script side:

Please set `URLPARENTFOLDER` and `URLSHEET`.

```
function addNewRow(array,obj) {
  var timestamp = new Date();
  var parentFolderId = "URLPARENTFOLDER";
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId);
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var folderName = "SIP "+array.numsip+"/"+array.rut;
  var foldercreated = parentFolder.getFoldersByName(folderName);
  foldercreated = foldercreated.hasNext() ? foldercreated.next() : parentFolder.createFolder(folderName);
  var idfolder= foldercreated.getId()
  var url = "URLSHEET";
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ss= values.getSheetByName("DATA");
  ss.appendRow([array.numsip,array.rut,timestamp,user,idfolder]);
  return obj.map(({fileName, mimeType, data}) => {
    var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(data), mimeType, fileName);
    return foldercreated.createFile(blob).getId();
  });
}
```

#### Javascript side:

Please modify `enviardatos()` in Javascript side as follows.

From:

```
[...f.files].forEach((file, i) => {
const fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = (e) => {
  const data = e.target.result.split(",");
  const obj = {fileName: f.files[i].name, mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1], data: data[1]};
  
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((id) => {console.log(id);}).addNewRow(array, obj);
}
fr.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

To:

```
Promise.all([...f.files].map((file, i) => {
  const fr = new FileReader();
  return new Promise((r, rj) => {
    fr.onload = (e) => {
      const data = e.target.result.split(",");
      r({fileName: f.files[i].name, mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1], data: data[1]});
    }
    fr.onerror = (e) => rj(e);
    fr.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
}))
.then(obj => google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(console.log).addNewRow(array, obj))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

#### References:

- [getFoldersByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfoldersbynamename)
- [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Wow! works excellent. I was not familiar with the Promise function at all. Thank you very much @Tanaike both for the answer and the knowledge provided, I have one more question. With my above code I was able to get the ids of the files, how is it possible to get the ids of the files in the folder and set the registry in the sheets? greetings!

Comment: Thank you again @Tanaika, i will follow your recommendation for future questions, but regarding to the new issue, it will not be necessary to generate a question, because actually accessing the folder with allí files, everything is easier. Greetings!